# how to uninstall Xcode (do not have /Developer folder or "Install Xcode" app)

Tags: xcode, osx-lion

this is a strange question. I search for a while but no luck. I have installed Xcode on lion previously; however I delete the "Install Xcode" after the installation. Now when I use commands like "g++" and "make", which should be supported by Xcode, terminal says "command not found". Also, there is no Developer folder at my home path; all I have is a Xcode app in my Application folder. But I could open it and also compile c program in it.

I am confusing about this situation now, so I decide to uninstall and reinstall Xcode. However  I cannot directly drag the Xcode app to trash. Is there a way to get this back to the right track? I need to use those command line tools.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may cause due to some files has been moved to trash by mistake.

Download new XCODE from http://connect.apple.com for Lion 10.7.3 and upgrade your mac OS to the latest version.Then reinstall it again after deleting the previous XCODE.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to delete the Xcode, which I though to be un-deletable. Now reinstall a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Command-line build tools are now a separate install within XCode.app. Look under the "Downloads" tab of the preferences panel, under "Components".

Comment: I see that, but every time I try to download the tool it says cannot connect to the server; maybe some files of Xcode lost. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

XCode 4.3 does not use a /Developer folder and does not install the command line tools by default. Go to preferences in Xcode, downloads, and install the command line tools. Or, you can download Xcode 4.2.x directly from Apple.